# Apache error log question

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I keep seeing the following error in Apache error log. Anyone has any idea what this is?

```
client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23):
/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://isc.sans.org/diary.html?storyid=900 it's an exploit scanner. Nothing to be concerned about if you are up to date, I've got them in my logs too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a client who is trying to access the resource `/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind` on your server, but the client has been implemented poorly and not followed [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23), which states:

> A client MUST include a Host header
>   field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages
>   . If the requested URI does not
>   include an Internet host name for the
>   service being requested, then the Host
>   header field MUST be given with an
>   empty value.

Its probably some poorly written bot.